# NPM ERROR: EINTEGRITY: Integrity checksum failed using sha 512

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

Been having this issue when running an npm install command. Have tried almost everything on the forums on force cleaning cache, clean npm install with deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, etc.

Nothing has been working. Hoping to understand the root cause and what I can do. Debug log found below:

```
lerna ERR! npm run precommit exited 1 in '<folder>'
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
PS C:\Users\T955082\Documents\GitHub\cio-iof-bird-ui\packages\cio-iof-bird-report-ui> npm install
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-FCEhQ/4rE1zYv9rYXJw/msRqsnmlje5jHP6huWeBZ704jUTy02c5AZyWujpMR1ax6mVw9NyJMfuK2CMDWVIfgA== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-FCEhQ/4rE1zYv9rYXJw/msRqsnmlje5jHP6huWeBZ704jUTy02c5AZyWujpMR1ax6mVw9NyJMfuK2CMDWVIfgA== but got sha512-qILHacp4rxtTdIkkEvz0OdxpExfzZ0zlqJ0rBUx1RFmSH86OtRpKIprmsFrfCS837gV9yDDyQqdxD8diFsKqwQ==. (64727 bytes)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `npm cache verify` and if that doesn't work `npm clean`.

from https://www.ludofischer.com/blog/npm-cache-error/

Answer (score 2):

Delete the node_modules and package-lock.json file.

Run npm cache clear --force

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different use case for this issue. I had pulled some changes from the master branch and that was giving me these errors. What solved it for me was removing the current package-lock.json and using the package-lock.json of the last functional commit and running:

`npm install`

That seemed to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with node `16.3` after upgrading to the latest lts version by running `nvm install --lts` changing to version `16.16` and deleting node_modules, it's working now.